# Proper way to use `udev` rules with `/dev/uhid`

Tags: linux, udev

I want to set the group of `/dev/uhid` on Linux to `uhid` so that users of that group have rw access without root privileges. Unfortunately rules like `KERNEL=="uhid", GROUP="uinput-users", MODE="0660"` don't get applied on startup (udev doesn't even know the device), but when I access `/dev/uhid` once with root access.

Example:

```
sugar@achilles:~$ udevadm info /dev/uhid
Unknown device "/dev/uhid": No such device
sugar@achilles:~$ sudo ./some/random/program/that/accesses/uhid 
[sudo] password for sugar: 
^C
sugar@achilles:~$ udevadm info /dev/uhid
P: /devices/virtual/misc/uhid
N: uhid
L: 0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/misc/uhid
E: DEVNAME=/dev/uhid
E: MAJOR=10
E: MINOR=239
E: SUBSYSTEM=misc
```

```
sugar@achilles:~$ ls -la /etc/udev/rules.d/90-uinput.rules 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 42 Aug 12 22:58 /etc/udev/rules.d/90-uinput.rules
sugar@achilles:~$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/90-uinput.rules 
KERNEL=="uhid", GROUP="udev", MODE="0660"
```

(I tried different things but the example above is from here: https://gist.github.com/StuntsPT/cd3ef67a5ac30e168cb6774ea939f55f)

Can somebody tell me why this is and how I can fix it? The only explanation I could come up with is that `/dev/uhid` is created before `udev` is "ready".

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `uhid` module is only loaded "on demand", i.e. when accessing the `/dev/uhid` the first time. The udev rule is applied when loading the module. This can be easily fixed by adding `uhid` to `/etc/module` to load the module during boot.